# Can not connect to mysql server on localhost (0)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

i am trying to connect mysql server using sqlyog and phpmyadmin but it's not working.

```
MySQL (phpmyadmin) said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=%Id
 mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=8064
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=%Id
 mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=8064
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You 
 should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they 
 correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

This is my xampp my.ini setting

```
[client]
password = 
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
# Here follows entries for some specific programs 
# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=15501
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
```

and when i am trying to connect using SQLyog

```
lost connection to mysql server at handshake, reading initial communication packet
```

Comment: `port=15501` WHY? And are you telling your tool that mariaDB is listening on a non standard port?

Comment: client & server must work on the same port

Comment: it was a same port and i saw one solution so i have changed but same

Comment: socket on C:/xampp... ? Windows doesn't support unix sockets

Answer (score 0):

i have just uninstall xampp and reinstall new one and it's resolve my problem